# BS4 import is not working in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I am new to python. I want to run python scripts in eclipse as i am bit comfortable with that. I am trying to import and run Beautiful Soup in eclipse oxygen.Import is successful,but I am getting an error(un-resolved import soup) with following code.However beautiful soup is working fine with anaconda.[enter image description here][1]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

Comment: does `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` works? Also try to add `import sys. sys.path.append("path/to/bs4")` to ensure python can search the package.

Comment: (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bs4) is what I think is installed BS4 path.Correct me. And suggest me how to give sys.path.append("path/to/bs4").

Comment: Then I think the issue is because Eclipse unable to properly find the bs4 package location for you. Try `import sys` then `sys.path.append("C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bs4")`

Comment: Bad Luck!!! 
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bs4")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq

Still showing error

Comment: can you import BeautifulSoup only first since you mention it's working? and what error is shown this time?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I figured I would post the answer that worked for me.

The trick is to use the folder that the bs4 is in. For the asker above it would be

```
sys.path.append("C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages")
```

I'm guessing because import is looking for a package named bs4-- of which, inside the bs4 package itself, there is none.